# Given an inequality of two meromorphic functions, prove that they are equal up to a constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

The following is a past qualifying exam question in complex analysis:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be two meromorphic functions in $\mathbb{C}$.  Assume that $|f(z) + g(z)| \le |g(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ which are not poles of either $f$ or $g$.  Show that there is some constant $c$, with $|c+1| \le 1$, such that $f(z) = cg(z)$.

My intuition would be to use Rouche's Theorem to show that $f/g$ would be entire, and then we would have the result by Louiville's Theorem; but I've been unable to make this a reality.  Any hints?

Comment: Divide by $|g(z)|$ to deduce $f(z)/g(z)+1$ is bounded.

Comment: Sure, but why is $f/g$ entire?

Comment: Meromorphic implies holomorphic except at poles, and if it'd had poles it wouldn't be bounded. So it's holomorphic on the whole plane, i.e. entire.

Comment: $f/g$ is defined and bounded except at  poles of $f$ and $g$. Then use Riemann's theorem on removable singularities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{f(z)+g(z)}{g(z)}-1$. Then $\bigl|h(z)+1\bigr|\leqslant1$ for each $z$ at which $h(z)$ is defined. You can extend $h$ to an entire function, by [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem). So, by Liouville's theorem, $h$ is a constant function $c$ and, of course, $c$ is such that $|c+1|\leqslant1$.